# What are the Sensors/Flow Meters Required for Automated Fault Detection & Diagnosis in a HVAC system?

Tags: sensors, hvac, systems-engineering

Automated fault detection and diagnosis is a very promising area of implementation to reduce energy consumption by buildings. A lot of research has been done in this area, but most of it is about the analysis and usage of the generated data. I am new to the field of HVAC, and my first project is on a HVAC retrofit for a building that was commissioned in 1998. My questions, to which I haven't been able to find a concrete answers are:

1. What are the basic sensors/flow meters required to generate useful data for usage in AFDD? The current building I am studying has absolutely no sensors, and no BMS; or
2. What are the areas of an HVAC system that need sensors/flow meters?
   All the research papers I found till now deal with the data processing and making-sense-of-it. What I need to know is, **how do I get the data**?

Comment: The first thing you will need to specify is exactly what faults you are looking to detect.

Comment: Ideally, all kinds of faults that would lead to a system shut down.
In the case of the chillers, low/high refrigerant charge, valve leakage, condenser/evaporator fouling, filter/dryer restriction. For the chilled water lines, any leaking, stagnation, etc. Also, the ones related to the AHUs, like problems with the fans, stuck dampeners for VAV boxes, etc.

Comment: If you are trying to identify only one end condition, eg. "temperature out of expected range", that's not too bad. But each one of these things will require specific sensors. If you're clever there may be some overlap.

Comment: Please add a list of all conditions you would like to detect to your question. As it stands the question is far too vague.